# Angular doesnt update changes without reloading page.how can I overcome this?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

when I reload page I'm getting a warning saying that "Tried to load angular more than once".But I didn't import angular script more than once.
If any one please give any answer for this question

Comment: can you post you code then we can try to resolve your issue

Comment: i all browser or only IE

Answer (score 1):

Its a generic errors it could have many reasons to get this warning. I will try to give suggestions for two cases

first it's a problem of routeProvider not finding a file and recursively loading the default.

```
 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/listing.html',
    controller: 'ListingCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

if you are using ui-view then it should be like below

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

3. You have to add jquery script tag before angularjs so that angularjs can replace jqLite by jQuery.

script loading order should be like below

```
jquery.js
jqueryui.js
angular.js
```

Comment: now the warning is gone.but still when i update data it doesnt show any updates in table untill i reload.